# Basic bricks in Ninjago Spinners sets

Tags: ninjago

Every Ninjago spinner set contains basic bricks of the same color: two 1X2 bricks and a 2x2 flat.

See:
http://brickset.com/sets?query=spinners

What is the purpose for these bricks?

Answer (score 4):

These parts are used to hold the cards upright as shown in the instructions:

[image: Spinners card holder]